# Strpos can never find needle in haystack? (Using !==)

Tags: php, string, strpos

```
for($i = 0; $i < 60; $i++)
{
    foreach($lines as $line_num => $line)
    {   
        if(strpos(strtolower($items[$i]['username']), strtolower($line)) !== false)
        {
            var_dump("found");
        }   
    }
}
```

I have 60 names in the $items array, for each name i'm checking it against another array containing names i'm looking for with strpos, however it NEVER seems to detect the string even though it's testing the following:

ashley.gram20 : ashley <- Does not show found.

It quite clearly should have found 'Ashley.gram20' surely? but it never does?

Thanks!

Comment: `strpos('A','a') === false`, but `stripos('A', 'a') === true`

Comment: Does var_dump($line); say string(7) "ashley"?

Comment: can you show us the exact string in the haystack and your needle? the if clause should be true if there maybe aren't any whitespaces or sth. else in your needle `ashley`

Comment: @TML Yes prints: 'ashley'

Comment: The key part of my question has been ommitted in your answer. Does it say `string(7)`?

Comment: @TML I think i see where you're going with that... Doh.

Comment: Darn, and I thought I was being subtle about it. :) Check out [rtrim](http://php.net/rtrim) and make sure to answer your own question if this turns out to be the problem!

Comment: @TML Woops sorry about the late response! Of course that was the problem... hate bugs like that. Thanks for giving me the nudge!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved! Thanks to @TML for giving me the nudge in the right direction, was simply some invisible character on the end of the string! (Not a space, which i'd already cleaned the string of).

Now using:

```
rtrim($target);
```

While will trim all spaces and non standard chars from a string, the more you know!

Answer (score 0):

My guess is you should use the following code:

```
for($i = 0; $i < 60; $i++)
{
    foreach($lines as $line_num => $line)
    {   
        if(strpos(strtolower($line), strtolower($items[$i]['username'])) !== false)
        {
            var_dump("found");
        }   
    }
}
```

For `strpos` you need to have first **haystack** and **needle** as second parameter and not opposite as you probably did.

Of course you could use `stripos` instead of `strpos`:

```
for($i = 0; $i < 60; $i++)
{
    foreach($lines as $line_num => $line)
    {   
        if(stripos(line, $items[$i]['username']) !== false)
        {
            var_dump("found");
        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: username is to be the haystack yes, and the line is the needle, the order was correct i think, i also used stripos for the exact same result!

Answer (score -1):

You alsmost got it right, but you forgot one foreach, so **$line** were still an array and not a string.

```
<?php

$lines = array(array('Test','Monk','donky.monster'));

$items = array(array('username' => 'donky'),array('username' => 'Test'));

foreach($items as $item)
{
    foreach($lines as $line_num => $line)
    {
      foreach($line as $name){
        if(strpos(strtolower($item['username']), strtolower($name)) !== false)
        {
            var_dump("found");
        }
      }
    }
}
?>
```

Demo: https://eval.in/201652

Comment: $line is just a string, not an array, which would give me  Invalid argument supplied for foreach()